# Is religious discrimination legal in public in the USA?

Tags: united-states, law, religion

It has happened in Houston in front of a  shopping center:

[image]

I had heard something similar about some shops and stores using similar signs and hate speeches in the 70s and before it in New York City and other big cities against Jews and Greeks, and before those against blacks. After years and years and changes in minds and behaviors by education and communication, it seems terribly ugly and unbelievable!

Is such religious discrimination legal in the United States today?

Comment: Very interesting. I think nothing like this can happen in Russia. This would spark a loud scandal and trigger a criminal investigation. But Russians can be more inventive - for example, hire a Christian priest to "bless" the cars periodically with holy water.

Comment: http://m.now.msn.com/no-muslim-parking-signs-displayed-in-lot-across-from-houston-mosque the article says that the shopping parking space may have been used by non-customers go to a mosque. My speculation: the owner of the store is not a native English speaker, and phrased his statement badly?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: I'm in agreement with Mr. Grimm. Most likely, the sign was meant in the line of "everyone else follows the rules and doesn't use our lot as free parking, except for people coming to that mosque. So we need a special sign just for them to make the rules more obvious to them". Not exactly the most sensitive, nice or smart thing to do and say, but not an unexpected reaction when a group of people violates rules and your property in large numbers.

Comment: If a parking spot excludes people of a religion, that's discrimination.

Comment: @Avi - a parking spot != posted hand-made sign. That's the whole point. Did they explicitly tow away Muslim owners' cars and leave along those of other religions? If no, no discrimination took place.

Comment: If the sign caused a Muslim not to park there, then discrimination occurred.

Comment: I am curious why you need the picture above for this question. You said it better explains New York, but your question doesn't include any pictures from NY. For the vision imparred, text is actually preferable to pictures. Why is this picture so important that you feel it is necessary to discriminate against the blind? Additionally, this could be generalized to match NY with are "NO [insert religion/race]" signs illegal? (Since you find this statement racist, why inflict it on us?) I wonder, since my edit included a link to the news article included a similar picture and gave **context** to th

Comment: I found the previous picture offensive, so have instead linked to the appropriate news article. I have also included the text of the sign, but have generalized it (so it matches the Civil Rights Era signs you said existed in NY in the '70s). If you can justify the existence of the offensive picture, feel free to provide the justification and edit the question.

Comment: If that picture is offensive, it is not my question's fault! The reality of such action is offensive and this question helps to find what and why and how you can stop it!.. Even by -100 you can't change the offensive reality of this picture to a positive action. So I am sorry for showing an offensive picture which is necessary to know about the feelings which a sign or hate speech can make in the world. I hope you understand it. Do not hesitate to downvote it but if you try radical edits again I will reverse it to the reality again. :)

Comment: I have included all your information, you cannot possibly find it objectionable.

Comment: It is not by you to decide about what I have to write here and what not! SE doesn't work like this as far as I know! You can show your disagreement by closing votes or downvotses or even deleting votes or discussing in the meta site but not by this childish method in insisting to forcing your decisions to the others! I rejected your edit as I do not want to add some information which it may be different from one site/news paper to another site/news paper but it seems you could not realize it and only want to force your idea to the others! OK! You can continue but I will reject it again.

Comment: @PersianCat, [feel free to justify your position here](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/how-should-we-handle-offensive-images-in-questions-or-obvious-soapboxing).

Comment: @DVK: I suspect you and Andrew are onto what's really going on.  I find it *highly* unlikely that the owners/operators of the parking lot was engaged in blatant religious discrimination.  They instead should have written the sign to say "No Mosque Parking", which wouldn't be discriminatory at all.

Comment: Why downvotes? The question addresses a real problem. Personal opinions shouldn't be the reason to downvote on any SE site (excluding, of course, meta)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some religious discrimination in the US is legal, but it depends on by whom it is being committed, and it what context. The first and 14th amendments prohibit discrimination based on religion (or, in the 14th amendment's case, in general) for the federal and state governments.

The [First Amendment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Text):

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech

The [Fourteenth Amendment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Text):

> No State shall make or enforce any law which shall abridge the privileges or immunities of citizens of the United States; nor shall any State deprive any person of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law; nor deny to any person within its jurisdiction the equal protection of the laws.

Since [Bolling v. Sharpe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolling_v._Sharpe), a Supreme Court decision from 1954, the Fifth amendment has also been interpreted to imply equal protection under federal law. The fourtheenth amendment applies only to the states.

Religious discrimination by the government is subject to the standard of [strict scrutiny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_Lukumi_Babalu_Aye_v._City_of_Hialeah), which means that the discrimination must be necessary to further a significant government interest, narrowly tailored to further that interest, and must be the least restrictive means of doing so. Otherwise, it's unconstitutional.

Private discrimination against religion is also regulated: the Civil Rights Act prohibits religious discrimination in [hiring, payment, employment benefits, etc.](http://www.dol.gov/dol/topic/discrimination/ethnicdisc.htm)

However, hate speech in the US, including hate speech targeted at religion, is legal in the US. The First Amendment guarantees freedom of speech, and the Supreme Court ruled in [R.A.V v. City of St. Paul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.A.V._v._City_of_St._Paul) that the fact that laws against calls to violence were constitutional did not mean that laws against hate speech were constitutional, as hate speech did not constitute "fighting words".

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 separate issues here:

1. *Q: Is that specific sign "illegal" or even "discrimination"?*

   A1: According to the article, nobody admitted to posting the sign (and the store owner plans to remove it). Therefore, since the sign is not a factual policy of any public or private entity and merely someone's personal piece of paper, it's not illegal (see Avi's answer re: hate speech).

   A2: Moreover, based on the facts in the article, **it's nowhere near "discrimination"**. The owners indicated that they would tow EVERYONE's car who's not a customer, Muslim or not - which is a normal policy in pretty much every private parking lot of any store I've ever been in. The only way this could be "discrimination" would be if the towing policy explicitly excluded non-Muslims. Therefore, the premise of the question (is ***such*** discrimination legal) is wrong since no discrimination took place.
2. Q: Now, let's assume the sign WAS indeed officially posted by the store (which it wasn't as per the article), as the store's official policy. Would **posting** such a policy be illegal?

   A: May be. This is a conflict between free speech and Civil Rights act. I'm not aware of any cases where it was decided, but absent discriminatory enforcement of this policy, the sign itself would likely still be legal. However, having such a sign might be a good way to be found in violation of #3.
3. Q. Let's say, it was an official policy (which it wasn't as per the article) AND it was enforced in such a discriminatory way.

   A. That WOULD be illegal.

   **The Federal Civil Rights Act** guarantees all people the right to "full and equal enjoyment of the goods, services, facilities, privileges, advantages, and accommodations of any place of public accommodation, without discrimination or segregation on the ground of race, color, religion, or national origin."

Answer (score 0):

**No, it is illegal**

Houston, Texas is inside Harris County. The Texas Legislature passed the [Bandit Sign Law](http://www.harriscountytx.gov/coatty/banditsigns.aspx) in 2007 (House Bill 413 that added civil penalties and empowered the County Attorney and District Attorney to take legal action to collect those penalties.

> The law prohibits posting a sign on property that is part of the road right of way. This includes signs nailed to utility poles, pasted to traffic control boxes, placed in medians and islands, or attached to traffic sign poles. Typically the public right of way extends beyond the paved portion of the road and includes sidewalks. Utility poles are usually in the public right of way.

[Section 393 of the Transportation Code](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/TN/htm/TN.393.htm) is the law that governs signs on public ways.

> Sec. 393.002. SIGN PLACEMENT PROHIBITED. Except as provided by Sections 393.0025 and 393.0026, a person may not place a sign on the right-of-way of a public road unless the placement of the sign is authorized by state law.

Comment: Relevant to the sign, but not to the question: he asked if religious discrimination was legal in the United States, not if that sign was legal in Texas.

Comment: @Avi, I disagree. Why include the picture unless it is relevant to the question. The question was, "Is religion discrimination legal in public in the USA? **It has happened in Houston** in front of a shopping center. [...] Is such racist **demonstration legal** in the USA nowadays?" So, the question is whether the particular demonstration of "racism" is legal. It clearly isn't, since this is Houston, TX (in Harris county) and that sign is clearly on the sidewalk.

Comment: The question was "is religious discrimination legal in public in the USA?" and the sign was an example. the question wasn't about the sign specifically. Ultimately the OP would have to clarify, but I think your answer missed the point was too narrow (whereas mine was likely too broad).

Comment: @Avi - a sign on private property won't be "in public discrimination" which was the focus of the question. So the fact that this was on a public roadway matters greatly to the question.

Comment: Yes, but 1873's answer doesn't address whether public discrimination is illegal in the US, just that placing a sign on a public roadway in Texas is illegal.

Comment: @Avi - that's a fault of poor question.

Comment: @Avi, as DVK points out, there are multiple problems with this question. 1) This isn't discrimination (a sign cannot discriminate). 2) The question is unclear, is it about "this particular" example or legality of all religious discrimination. Is it about public display of discrimination (as opposed to private), etc. The question also mixes racial/religious discrimination when it shouldn't. You claim my answer should address **all** racial discrimination in the US, but the question provides details which I would argue limit its scope.

Comment: Pretty clear this sign was in a shopping centre parking lot, not on the highway.

Comment: @DJClaworth,  Do you see the curb, the grass, and the sidewalk? What about the white lines (cross-walk) next to the "No Muslim" text in the background? It sure appears to me to be on the side of a public road. Whoever said it was on a highway? I think you need to reread my answer, and reexamine that picture (and the now.MSN image).

Comment: @BenCollins, "Typically the public right of way extends beyond the paved portion of the road and includes **sidewalks**." From the [news article](http://muslimvillage.com/2013/08/17/42651/no-muslim-parking-signs-at-texas-removed/) (that the OP keeps removing), "The posters **lined the street** near the El Farouq Mosque.". Or you can watch this video on the [huffpo](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/08/09/no-muslim-parking-_n_3733132.html) (min 1:21, 0:41, and countless other times). So, whenever you want to admit that you have no idea what public right of way is, feel free to.

Comment: @BenCollins, " Utility poles are usually in the public right of way." [Since I think](http://www.harriscountytx.gov/coatty/banditsigns.aspx) you are likely to be super pendantic. That sign is clearly hanging from a city pole of some sort, and that pole is grounded (1:20ish) in the dirt between the curb and the sidewalk, which is clearly public property.

Comment: @user1873: I will admit only that I was wrong :-).